# For which values of $a$ does the following LP problem have an optimal solution?

Tags: linear-programming

Let $a \in R$. For which values of $a$ does the following LP problem have an optimal solution?
$$max(2x_1+6x_2+3x_3)$$
$$-3x_2+ax_3 \geq 3$$
$$x_1+5x_2+2x_3=4$$
$$x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0$$

I solved it with the Big M Method and found that the LP problem has an optimal solution for $a>\frac{3}{2}$ and the value of the objective function is $8-\frac{3}{a}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphically, yes it is But ..... read it.
The second condition is a plane cuts the three axis  at $4,4/5,2$ respectively where the first one is the above the plane parallel to the first axis and cuts the second and third axes at $-1,3/a$ respectively. If the intersection of these plane lie out side the first quad, the feasible region is empty. So, we have $$\frac{3}{a}<2 \implies a>\frac{3}{2} $$ Now you only a triangle with corners $(0,0,2),(-6/a,0,3/a), (0,(4a-6)/(6+5a),27/(6+5a))$. The first point gives $6$ and the second gives $8-3/a$. 
Finally, the values of $a$ is true but the max. value is also true

Comment: Shouldn't it be:$$\frac{3}{a}<2 \Rightarrow a>\frac{3}{2}$$?
So then it would be: $$\frac{3}{a}<2 \Rightarrow -\frac{3}{a}>-2 \Rightarrow 8-\frac{3}{a}>6$$

Comment: you are right, i will edit it now

Comment: I did the same mistake at the beginning...I will edit my post too...

Comment: now the value .5 is not valid

Comment: Yes..Now the value $8-\frac{3}{a}$ is the max, isn't it?

Comment: yes it is, glad to help out

Comment: Nice!!Thank you very much!!